# I want my (hero) image to crop when the screen size becomes smaller

Tags: css, html, image

I am trying to make a website, but I have a problem. I have a image, I need it to always fill the complete screen. Just like they do on this website: http://mollyandmepecans.com
This is my website: https://mountainweb-cemre2002.c9users.io/Homepage.html

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try 'background-size:cover' or may be setting a specific background position using `background-position: a px b px`

Comment: Go through this link and set the background properties for body day as per your requirement, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your image element, and then add this CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("MountEverest.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use the background, add this to your HTML to replace your image element:

```
<div class="hero"></div>
```

And this to your CSS:

```
.hero {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -100;

    background-image: url("MountEverest.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I have a slideshow set up, to show the images. I cannot set it to a background. –

Comment: OMG IT F*CKING WORKS!!! Thank you!!!!!! I worked hours to try to fix this! THANKS!

Comment: @CemreSuler No problem! Glad you're so happy ;P

Answer (score 0):

use object-fit if you need to cover img element.

```
.hero{
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/